# Bash variable expansion syntax with braces

Tags: bash, syntax, expansion

What does the following bash syntax mean?

```
MY_VAR=${MY_VAR:-"mystring"}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See *Parameter Expansion* in `man bash`:

> ${parameter:-word}
>
> Use Default Values.  If `parameter` is unset or null, the expansion of `word`  is  substituted.
>      Otherwise, the value of `parameter` is substituted.